# ES6 specific method to loop through two arrays and find matches in each?

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have two arrays of objects that I want to compare:

```
var arr1 = [
  {
    name: 'A', type: "Dog"
  },
  {
    name: 'B', type: "Zebra"
  },
  {
    name: 'C', type: "Cat"
  },
  {
    name: 'D', type: "Dingo"
  }
]

var arr2 = [
  {
    name: 'A', type: "Wolf"
  },
  {
    name: 'B', type: "Echidna"
  },
  {
    name: 'C', type: "Wallaby"
  },
  {
    name: 'D', type: "Rabbit"
  }
]
```

Pretend that `arr1` is old data, and `arr2` is updated data coming from an API.

I want to loop through the arrays, finding objects whose `name` matches. If there is a match, I want to update the `type` from `arr1` to `arr2`.

I'd do this like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i<arr1.length; i++){
  for(var x = 0; x<arr2.length; x++){
    if(arr1[i].name === arr2[x].name){
      arr1[i].type = arr2[x].type;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm wondering if there are any updated ways in ECMAScript 6 which make this easier to do (in a real world scenario the logic is a lot more complex and looping within a loop feels rather clunky);

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or `findIndex`

Comment: Will all objects have different names?

Comment: @Oriol Yes, the `name` is a unique identifier. Sometimes `arr2` will introduce names that weren't in `arr1`, which will need to be inserted.

Comment: If name is a unique identifier, then you should probably use those as keys in an object so you always have constant time lookup as opposed to having to iterate through two arrays to find matches.

Answer (score 5):

In ES2015 you wouldn't use this data structure, you would use [maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map):

```
var map1 = new Map([
  ['A', "Dog"],
  ['B', "Zebra"],
  ['C', "Cat"],
  ['D', "Dingo"]
]);
var map2 = new Map([
  ['A', "Wolf"],
  ['B', "Echidna"],
  ['C', "Wallaby"],
  ['D', "Rabbit"]
]);
```

And then, to update `map1` with the data from `map2`, you would use

```
for(let [key, value] of map2)
  map1.set(key, value);
```

Map operations are required to be sublinear on average. They should be constant if the map is implemented with a hash. Then the total cost would be linear.

Alternatively, since the keys are strings, you can consider using a plain object. You can create it with [`Object.create(null)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) to prevent it from inheriting properties from `Object.prototype`, and assign the properties with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```
var obj1 = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
  A: "Dog",
  B: "Zebra",
  C: "Cat",
  D: "Dingo"
});
var obj2 = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
  A: "Wolf",
  B: "Echidna",
  C: "Wallaby",
  D: "Rabbit"
});
```

And then, to update `obj1` with the data from `obj2`, you would use

```
for(let key in obj2)
  obj1[key] = obj2[key];
```

Most probably the object will be implemented using a hash, so each assignment will be constant on average. The total cost would be linear.

Comment: Even in an array of more complex objects? (the real-world data has far more keys and values). This question is more cursory / generic than trying to apply to my own use-case, but I'm interested in what works in the real world here too.

Comment: @Jascination Yes, why not? Map operations are required to be sublinear on average, so it's a good option. Or, since the keys are strings, old `Object.create(null)` would be a good alternative.

Comment: I think you'll need to add a `if (map1.has(key))` / `if (key in obj2)` condition to accurately fullfill OP's requirements

Comment: @Bergi OP [said](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35711999/1529630#comment59101049_35711999) "*Sometimes `arr2` will introduce names that weren't in `arr1`, which will need to be inserted*", so no need to check.

Comment: @Oriol: Ah, I see - it's just different behaviour from the nested loops he had.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a forEach loop (ES5) or the for..of loop from ES6:

```
for (let item1 of arr1) {
  for (let item2 of arr2) {
    if(item1.name === item2.name){
      item1.type = item2.type;
    }
  }
}
```

If these lists are quite long I would suggest putting the updated list into a hash map so your time complexity is linear rather than quadratic.